# Web App SPA & OIDC: How to properly authenticate before accessing the front?

Tags: angular, authentication, single-page-application, openid-connect

I have a regular web app, composed as usual of a frontend SPA (angular) and a backend.

The server calls are protected from unauthorized calls through authentication provided by OpenID Connect.

My web app is accessible from the internet, and though the front by itself does not contain any user data (which is saved in a database in the backend), I still want to prevent non-users from accessing my front code, because it would leak features that I don't want non-users to know about.

Similarly, I also want to prevent regular users from being able to see admin features (`/admin` part of my website).

I know the whole point of SPA is to download everything in a single page load and then make dynamic changes, but I still want users to only download code for which they have appropriate rights (for example, you can download the 3 tabs of the main menu in one go if you have access rights for these 3 tabs, but the admin page can only be downloaded if you have admin rights).

What options do I have to make sure the user is authenticated and authorized before downloading front code, and what are their advantages / drawbacks ?

Comment: Tell us what you have tried and show code, logs or results and Read:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HMTL**

Usually in an SPA there is a single index.html file, as in [this online SPA of mine](https://authguidance.com/home/code-samples-quickstart/). So when following a pure SPA architecture the HMTL reveals no information.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no'>

        <base href='/spa/' />
        <title>OAuth Demo App</title>

        <link rel='stylesheet' href='bootstrap.min.css?t=1651226315563' integrity='sha256-YvdLHPgkqJ8DVUxjjnGVlMMJtNimJ6dYkowFFvp4kKs='>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='app.css?t=1651226315563' integrity='sha256-B7pu+gcFspulW4zXfgczVtPcEuZ81tZRFYeRciEzWro='>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='root' class='container'></div>

        <script type='module' src='vendor.bundle.js?t=1651226315563' integrity='sha256-Rbqz3uAj5ST2WPw7vI0qTgvMYpLa5mzM85xgl96MRKI='></script>
        <script type='module' src='app.bundle.js?t=1651226315563' integrity='sha256-9vJJYO5Z/3lk5cbSuR+W0RW9QFA9ObGYLAXPBeL4pkY='></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If multiple HTML files are returned, this is more of a website approach, and website stacks tend to protect HTML files using cookies to prevent any disclosure.

**JAVASCRIPT**

Javascript has traditionally not been secured in either SPAs or website tech stacks, since you need to allow Javascript to download in order to render an initial page, eg with a login button.

My deployed Javascript application code is not secured and is available in [this bundle file](https://web.authsamples.com/spa/app.bundle.js). It is minified, so also does not reveal much. Of course, there should be nothing really secret in UI logic, and APIs should be making all security decisions for the SPA.

My SPA could use a package such as [Javascript Obfuscator](https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/javascript-obfuscator) to further hide Javascript logic. The reason I have not done this is that exception stack trace lookup from source maps no longer works, but I would use obfuscation if I could find a solution where this was supported.

**MULTIPLE JAVASCRIPT RESOURCES**

If you need to secure Javascript you will need to build the SPA into multiple bundles such as these. Some [website stacks](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/92ba8346-0547-4bf3-af60-f06d4c1d451b/deny-directly-access-to-javascript-files?forum=iissecurity) provide this type of option, by hosting secured assets in a different folder. The web backend then checks that requests for those assets have an auth cookie:

```
- /unsecured/app-unauthenticated.bundle.js
- /secured/app-area1.bundle.js
- /secured/app-area2.bundle.js
```

You would need to look into [code splitting and lazy loading](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/lazy-loading-angular-code-splitting-webpack). In your app you can control when dynamic inports occur, so your code would never request secured bundles when the user is unauthenticated.

**AUTHORIZATION CHECKS**

If you are concerned about a hacker accessing your JS bundles outside of your own code, as for my bundle above, then you `could` secure access to bundle files by checking for cookies, or even going so far as checking claims in underlying OAuth access tokens, though I would not do any of this.

My web host is the AWS Cloudfront Content Delivery Network (CDN), where Lambda Edge Extensions can run code before assets are served. Currently the only role of my [lambda edge code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/tree/master/aws/lambda-edge/src) is to serve a default document and issue recommended web security headers.

This code could be updated to make the same cookie checks as [API gateway code](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.tokenhandler.serverless/blob/main/src/oauth-proxy/oauthProxy.ts), eg to return a 401 JSON response if it a valid cookie was not supplied. It would add considerable complexity though, and it is more standard to ensure at design time that UI code does not need securing.

**SUMMARY**

SPA security architecture is done best by separating web and API concerns. Personally I would put all my security efforts into securing APIs, and stick to obfuscation for Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you go into more depth as to how to "secure Javascript" as you said, which is really the heart of my question (obfuscation is not enough security) ? For example with angular, how would that bundle splitting work, and who's in charge of checking access rights, and how ?

Comment: I added a couple of points above. Access rights are an API concern. It is up to you to design who can access what - and it is not standard to apply that type of logic to Javascript bundles

Comment: I don't understand why concerns that existed prior to the SPA model are no longer standard. Whether you can actually use a feature or not, I consider listing the feature by itself to be information leakage. For example (I didn't check), would you expect Facebook to leak what kind of admin tools they have (even when you can't access them) ? Not to mention additional security risks by exposing this information. By analogy in a network environment, it would be like providing a map of your internal network to outsiders, regardless or not whether they have access to it.

Comment: I don't think securing JS was ever very standard in websites either, but it is possible if you have special reasons. Facebook might be a good option to base your own solution on. If you use browser tools to trace HTTP requests after a  Facebook login, identify JS URLs for secured views, then see if you can download them with commands of this form: 'curl https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/.../someresource.js'.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [CanLoad](https://angular.io/api/router/CanLoad) guard to check user permissions.

This guard will not only determine if users can navigate to a given route, it will also prevent the download of the module code when not authorized.

Comment: Isn't this check performed by the browser, and thus, modifiable by the end user ? I'm not just looking for lazy loading / performance improvements, but really for security through authentication / authorization.